# How to recode missing values in pandas dataframe using lookup table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather large dataframe of which a small portion of it is shown as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-1, 15, 0],
                  'B': [np.nan, 50, 4],
                  'C': [30, 5, 30,],
                  'D': [15, 2, np.nan],
                  'E': [8, 5, 99],
                  'F': [45, 7, np.nan],
                  'G': [1, 0, 35]})
```

Other than NaN, there are actually other missing codes as indicated in the accompanying feature dataframe.

```
feature_info= pd.DataFrame({
                'feature': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 
                'missing_info': ['[-1, 0]', '[]', '[]', '[X]', '[99]', '[]', '[1,0]']})
```

Notice the quotation marks around the list of missing values for each feature.

How can I do a lookup to the missing codes to replace the values in the respective columns in df?

---

**Subsequent update to my question** as I realise the ast liter returns a **ValueError: malformed node or string** if I have other datatypes in the missing info column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-1, 15, 0],
                  'B': [np.nan, 50, 4],
                  'C': [30, 5, 30,],
                  'D': [15, 2, np.nan],
                  'E': [8, 5, 99],
                  'F': ['X', 7, np.nan],
                  'G': [1, 0, 35]})

 feature_info= pd.DataFrame({
                    'feature': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 
                    'missing_info': ['[-1, 0]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[99]', '[X]', '[1,0]']})
```

Comment: are you able to provide a sample output?

Comment: Hi @RaymondToh . Forgot to attach the sample output. But Sharma's reply below for the sample output. (Though now I have updated my question somewhat and the nice ast module solutions provided fail.   :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description of the question it seems like you would want to replace the missing codes with the `NaN` values. Here is how I would approach this problem

- Evaluate the strings in `missing_info` columns as python lists using `literal_eval`
- Create a series `d` by setting the index to `feature` and selecting the `feature_info` column
- For each column in the dataframe `df`, mask the values which also occur for the corresponding index name in series `d`

```
import ast

d = feature_info.set_index('feature')['missing_info'].map(ast.literal_eval)

for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].mask(df[c].isin(d[c]))
```

---

```
      A     B   C     D    E     F     G
0   NaN   NaN  30  15.0  8.0  45.0   NaN
1  15.0  50.0   5   2.0  5.0   7.0   NaN
2   NaN   4.0  30   NaN  NaN   NaN  35.0
```

EDIT: If the list like strings in the `missing_info` column can contain strings in addition to integer then we can't be able to use `literal_eval`. Here is the alternative approach you can use in such case:

```
d = feature_info.set_index('feature')['missing_info']\
                   .str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s*')

for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].mask(df[c].astype(str).isin(d[c]))
```

Comment: Great thanks for apprising me the `ast` module!

Comment: @Lukas Happy coding!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma What an  elegant solution! But I realise ast.literal_eval line won't work if I have non-integers (e..g "X") in the lookup table... ?

Comment: @timpanister I've edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, it works for me now.Thank you@shubham sharma

Answer (score 0):

Extract missing values:

```
import ast
...
# create storage for incident values corresponding to feature_info
missing_indices = {}
# process each column from df 
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    missing_indices[col] = []
    for r in df.itertuples():
        # iterate over each row of the column, convert missing_info string into list of integers and compare 
        if r[i+1] in ast.literal_eval(feature_info.set_index('feature').loc[col, 'missing_info']):
            missing_indices[col].append(r.Index)
        elif pd.isna(r[i+1]):
            missing_indices[col].append(r.Index)      

missing_indices
```

Output:

```
{'A': [0, 2], 'B': [0], 'C': [], 'D': [2], 'E': [2], 'F': [2], 'G': [0, 1]}
```